# Can we use "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded" with application pages.?

Tags: client-object-model

Can we use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` in application pages. If yes, do I need to add `sp.js` to the project to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) supports on demand scripts, but [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not, I would recommend to use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` with `CSOM`:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    console.log(clientContext.get_url());
});
```

Comment: this one worked for me

Answer (score 6):

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded is a method used to delay a function call unless a particular script is loaded. Yes, you can use it in application page. If you are using CSOM you need to add a reference to sp.js file.

You can also use [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) if you are using on demand scripts.

A very good article on this is [here](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html)